# Problem with express Router with a react production build

Tags: reactjs, apache, express, production

Having issues routing the RESTful API in my deployment build of a React/express app.

I’ve set up a node app 'portfolio' as a subdomain in a subdirectory of a Ubuntu 16.04 server with apache2. There's been a lot of configuration trying to avoid paying another digital ocean droplet. I've managed to get my static react app in the correct subdomain with https.
I've come stuck at with the restful API.

var/www/html/portfolio/server.js contains:

```
import express from 'express';
import router from './routes/api/index';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`LISTENING on port ${port}`));
// Use middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(router);
```

portfolio/routes/api/index.js has some testing routes.
 Express.Router setup with routes like this:

```
    router.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
        res.send({ express: 'Express back-end, up and running!',
        });
    });
```

With pm2 logging, I can see that node is console logging some database queries to the console and other console.log commands.  Also checking what ports are listening I can see there is one listening on 5000.

However the issue is in deployment React is being served from portfolio/client/build/index.html and of course, the browser is directed to https://portfolio.domain.com from the server configuration files.

On localhost I can get request the route localhost:5000/api/hello.

However, this doesn’t work: https://portfolio.domain.com:5000/api/hello I’m guessing because, that requests -  portfolio/client/build/api/hello when the api is available :5000/portfolio/api/hello

EDIT: MORE INFO!!!

Now I've figured out that apache needs to be configured. For the 000-default.conf file I have a blank v/host:

```
 <VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
    # List of application servers:
    # Usage:
    # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # Example: 
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/

    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have SSL enabled on both my domain.com and portfolio.domain.com

```
Listen 443

NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine On

    # Set the path to SSL certificate
    # Usage: SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/file.pem


    # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
    # List of application servers:
    # Usage:
    # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # Example: 
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/

    # Or, balance the load:
    # ProxyPass / balancer://balancer_cluster_name

</VirtualHost>
```

With the directory structure of the production build, subdomain, SSL and so many moving parts I'm just not sure how to configure it.

Comment: You need to config your ```apache``` on sub location like ```/api``` to forward to your ```localhost:5000/api```.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand what you mean. I have an htaccess file in the root /html dir. I need to set a redirect somewhere? I would guess you might be suggesting that I create a htaccess file in /portfolio. Then redirect localhost:5000 to something like localhost:5000/client/build.  Yeah not enough info for me at the moment..